# How to return rows of data from a table with json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying out long polling and it works with textfile but I can't make it return everything from a table.

```
var timestamp = null;
function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'update.php?timestamp=' + timestamp,
        async: true,
        cache: false,

        success:function(data) {
            // alert(data);
            var json = eval('('+data+')');
            if (json['msg'] != '') {
                $('div.alltext').html(json['msg']); // MD
            }
            timestamp = json['timestamp'];
            setTimeout('waitForMsg()', 1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // alert('error '+textStatus+'('+errorThrown+')');
            setTimeout('waitForMsg()', 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

update.php

```
$filename = 'test.txt';

$lastmodif = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = filemtime($filename);

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) {
    usleep(10000);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filename); 
}
// how to rewrite the following?
$response = array();
$response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
```

How do I rewrite the last part to get everything from a DB table?

EDIT:

I tried the following but it only returns one result and not the newest one but the one before.

```
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $nou = $row['f1'];
    $nru = $row['f2'];
    $ntext = $row['content'];
    $ntime = $row['time'];
}

$response['msg'] = $ntext;
$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
```

Comment: So - did you make a research How to work with databases?

Comment: Yea. I will post now what i tried.

Comment: can you post the sql query you have executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning value outside of loop and because of that you are getting the last result. Assign the values inside loop.

```
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $nou = $row['f1'];
    $nru = $row['f2'];
    $response['msg'] = $row['content'];
    $response['timestamp'] = $row['time'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: This seems to be working! Just one thing: I get repeated result now every time, so if I write "hey", and then "hello", I will again get "hey" and THEN "hello", and so on. Basically, when I insert a new piece of text, the previous one first repeats itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array` replace `$ntext = $row['content'];` with `$ntext[] = $row['content'];`